# ASP.NET 5 and Angular Routing not working on dnx rc1

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, dnx

Hi I have a project built in ASP.NET 5 (dnxcore50 and dnx451). It is serving the requests for my AngularJS scripts. When I built the project I was using the Microsoft beta 5 dependencies  and using a rewrite rule to send all the requests to index.html and so my angular routing would work just fine. But today I had to upgrade to the rc1 dependencies and now my rewrite is not working and I'm just getting a 404 on my route. This new libraries added this weird lines of code to my web.config

```
  <handlers>
  <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" startupTimeLimit="3600" />
```

Is there a way how can I set my routing so that it works with angular for example if I go to localhost/shop it will redirect it to index.html and my angular routing will take over.

Comment: The web.config is to configure http platform handler to enable running your web with IIS. If you don't use IIS (which seems to be the case since you mention 404) you can ignore these entries.

Comment: I'm definitely using IIS express for development and IIS for releasing.

Comment: Do you have httpPlatformHandler 1.2 installed then?

Comment: Not that I'm aware off

Comment: I just installed it and it works in IIS now. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am on similar setup and I have in **Configure** in *Startup.cs*,

```
    app.UseDefaultFiles();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
```

and a rewrite rule in **system.webServer** in  *web.config*, needed that to be able to have both web api and index.html angular app served:

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!--Redirect selected traffic to index -->
        <rule name="Index Rule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/api/" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

You may need something similar too with your own rules

Comment: That is what I have, however I'm not sure which dnx version are you using, but after you upgrade to rc1 it will start adding the httpplatformhandler entries and the rewrites will stop working. I also see that you are using app.UseStaticFiles(), does that mean all your routes end in index.html?

Comment: You know what dude. Adding these three lines to my Configure method in startup fixed the problem, now my routing is working. Thanks!!   app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better way than using the url rewrite in the routing setup (So that there is no need for the url rewrite at all). E.g. I did this:

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "api",
                template: "api/{controller}/{action}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "angular",
                template: "{*url}",
                defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"},
                constraints: new {url = new DoesNotContainConstraint(".", "api/") });                
        });
```

This ensures that all /api goes to controllers and everything else goes to the Index. I had to do my own DoesNotContainConstraint to ensure that files and api with wrong url are properly handled, but it's rather easy.

Comment: That makes sense, however I don't have a single controller/action defined in my project because I expect angular to take control of the routing once it is redirected to index.html. My API is in a separate project so in this project I only have my angular scripts, views, etc. Is it possible to achieve this with the code you pasted there?

Comment: I think it is possible, you just need to add one controller that will return your index.html. But I guess you fixed it the other way now, but this solution is good if you don't want to use the url rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ASP.NET 5/ASP.NET Core with IIS you need to install HttpPlatformHandler. [Here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html) is a nice step by step instruction showing how to  install Http Platform Handler, configure IIS and publish an APS.NET Core application to IIS.