# ASP.NET Core map route to static file handler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on a ASP.NET Core website (previously named ASP.NET 5 / vNext) with Angular. In order for Angular to work I need to have a catch-all route:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(); 
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            // Angular fallback route
            routes.MapRoute("angular", "{*url}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });                
        });
```

I also have a few files/folders in wwwroot, like:

```
wwwroot/app
wwwroot/assets
wwwroot/lib
```

When any requests are made to these paths, for example `http://example.com/assets/css/test.css`, and the file (`test.css`) does NOT exist, it should not continue to the fallback route. It should return a 404.

Right now, if the file does not exist it returns the Angular HTML. So, how can I tell it that any path that starts with '/assets' should only be routed / served by `UseStaticFiles`?

Comment: Your default route poiting to any url "{*url}" is messing up the UseStaticFiles. The entry point for Angular could be only "/".

Comment: Yes, I know... how can I work around it? I need the default route for Angular.

Comment: You should point the default route to a static index.html file. There's no need to use MVC to render the Angular default entry point

Comment: I'm not using "hash" URL... Something like http://example.com/account/123 on first request would send a GET "/account/123" to the server. All these should return the default Angular loading HTML.

Comment: Then you should define something like "{angular}/{index}", because this "{*url}" will redirect any error, even for static files, to the defult url.

Comment: Do you mean that I should mirror all the possible Angular routes/URL on the server side? I guess that could work, but then I'd have to maintain that in two places (Angular and server-side).

Comment: Angular routes should be configured in Angular JS, There's no need to use MVC to route stuff, you should use only static files. As I said before, just use IIS to host the site, and configure the entry point in Web.config to an index.html file. Also, if you are using Html5Mode at your angular JS app you should take a deep look at how configure It to not conflic with server routes, saying again, server routes are not the same as angular js routes.

Comment: I think we're misunderstanding each other. I AM using Html5Mode  (Angular 2 defaults to that). Yes, I am handling the routes on Angular's side, but the server needs to be able to load Angular on any URL "/angular/url/foo/bar". The issues is that I need a few exceptions to the fallback route...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
app.MapWhen(
    context => {
        var path = context.Request.Path.Value.ToLower();
        return
            path.StartsWith("/assets") ||
            path.StartsWith("/lib") ||
            path.StartsWith("/app");
    },
    config => config.UseStaticFiles());
```

However, I'm not sure if there are any performance (or other type of) implications. I'll update if I come across any.

Answer (score 3):

It is strange that this common case (since many use SPA) is not covered almost anywhere and everyone has to invent something. I have found that the best way to do that is to add constraint (e.g. do not use the route if there is /api or "." in the path). Unfortunately this is not supported out of the box, but you can write this constraint yourself or copy the one I wrote from [here](https://github.com/ilya-git/Routing/commit/5e33d01b3de3a64e929d73133e6229c9f1eb65a4).

There are a bit more details in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35459088/1671558). But generally the code looks like this:

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "api",
            template: "api/{controller}/{action}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "angular",
            template: "{*url}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"},
            constraints: new {url = new DoesNotContainConstraint(".", "api/") });                
    });
```

P.S. Perhaps this constraint exist out of the box now, but I have not found one. Alternatively a RegEx can be used, but simple one should be way faster.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using **attribute template routing** then you can apply this elegant solution:

```
[HttpGet("")]
[HttpGet("{*route:regex(^(?!skipped).*$)}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Default(string route) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
```

So all routes started with *skipped* will be ignored by this action.
If you want multiple prefixes or anything else then just update regex for your needs.
First Get attribute is needed to handle root of site (in this case `route` variable is *null*).