# Routing Static Files in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Good day everyone.

I have tried several to make static files working through routing but is does not seem to work in IIS.

My current approach is this:

```
app.MapWhen(context =>
{
    var path = context.Request.Path.Value;
    return path.StartsWith("/Images", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}, config => config.UseStaticFiles());
```

Any clues what should I do in order make static files routing working?

Comment: have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/funamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2 maybe it's an issue of enabling directory browsing

Comment: Why are you using `MapWhen`? `UseStaticFiles()` by itself works. Are you trying to force a 404 for missing images as shown [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35587488/asp-net-core-map-route-to-static-file-handler)? That's only needed for Angular

Comment: @VishalPrajapati that's not what directory browsing is about, something [the docs point out with a security warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2#enable-directory-browsing). It's definitely not needed to enable static files. It's *extra* functionality with security implications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can access static Files in a folder named "Content" in the project Root.

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
      FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
      Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Content")),
      RequestPath = "/Content"
});
```

ex: http://localhost/content/myfile.html